# Watch and paste command

Tags: bash

I'm using the follow command to print side by side the output of two programs:

`paste <(cat log1.dat) <(cat log2.dat)`

I want to use the `watch` command to see both outputs together while the programs are running, like this:

`watch 'paste <(cat log1.dat) <(cat log2.dat)'`

However, when I try to run that, I get the following error:

`sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

I tried to escape the `(`, but had no success.

Comment: Might be better off for [unix.se]

Comment: `watch` starts `sh`, not `bash`. `<(...)` is a bash extension that `sh` does not offer. (But why would you need `cat` here at all?)

Comment: Have you considered `paste <(tail +0 -f log1.dat) <(tail +0 -f log2.dat)`? Then you don't need `watch` at all to see updates as new content is appended to the files.

Comment: (Also, `tail -f log1.dat log2.dat` will switch back-and-forth between showing `log1.dat1` and `log2.dat` as new content is found in either; again, no `watch` needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the shell used by `watch` doesn't support process substitution.

If you're running cat against a file, you should be able to simplify your command to this instead:

```
watch 'paste log1.dat log2.dat'
```

Alternatively, you could wrap your command in a shell that does support process substitution:

```
watch "bash -c 'paste <(cat log1.dat) <(cat log2.dat)'"
```

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is only for software development questions. As the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) specifies, questions that are not of exclusive interest to those writing software should be closed (in this case, with a pointer over to [unix.se]) rather than answered.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And who draws the line on what counts as software development?

Comment: Debate over where to draw that line is on-topic on [meta]. That said, the general rule I follow for shell-related tags is is "would this be a sensible thing to put in a script, or is it only something one would do at an interactive command line?"

Comment: ...using `watch` in a script is horrible, even just from an efficiency perspective -- you're running `sh -c` over and over (and over, and over). Thus, it's pretty strictly an interactive tool.

Comment: Okay, thanks for laying out your logic, that makes sense to me.